# How to manage dialogs in different router-views?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router, vuetify.js

I've got a problem with my `vue-router` and `v-dialog`s (**vuetify.js** components) inside different `router-view`s.

My `App.vue` looks like this:

```
<template>
  <transition>
    <keep-alive>
      <router-view/>
    </keep-alive>
  </transition>
</template>
```

Inside each `router-view` I have a component:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <app-header></app-header>
    <v-content></v-content>
    <app-footer></app-footer>

    <!-- a couple of dialogs here -->
    <v-dialog v-model="someData.show"></v-dialog>
    <v-dialog v-model="anotherData.show"></v-dialog>
    <v-dialog v-model="yetAnotherData.show"></v-dialog>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

When I switch between different `router-view`s and open dialogs overlay shows, but the dialog doesn't. Except for the `router-view` which was first loaded with the page.

What seems to be the problem? Does is have something to do with the way I define there routes or components?

You check full code over here: https://github.com/websanya/gkp7-app/

Please, help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact I should've used only one `v-app` outside of `router-view` in `App.vue` file.

```
<template>
  <!-- OVER HERE -->
  <v-app>
    <transition>
      <keep-alive>
        <router-view/>
      </keep-alive>
    </transition>
  </v-app>
  <!-- / OVER HERE -->
</template>
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: In case you didn't know: you can – and should – also accept own answers in order to make questions appear as "answered".

Comment: I knew, just couldn't accept my own answer before 2 days pass after posting. And the I forgot.